# while can i execute the script, i am getting this error org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: selenium, appium-android

I have written nearly 25 test case scripts. When I run the total scripts in Intellij idea, up to 12 scripts is working fine but while 13 script is running in middle of the session we are getting the error message like `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.`

Does anyone know a solution for this?

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=D:\esubcenter_mobile\eSubCenter_mobile\APK\eSubCenterQA-v1.1.12.9-debug(3).apk, noReset=true, platformVersion=6.0, platformName=Android, deviceName=192.168.59.101:5555}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DIPL-CP-PC004', ip: '192.168.59.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.lambda$1(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:96)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:96)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.doExecute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:112)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:73)
    at org.init.DriverInitalize.setDrivercaps(DriverInitalize.java:38)
    at org.init.TestBase.setDriver(TestBase.java:51)
    at org.init.TestBase.beforeMethod(TestBase.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)


Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.
```

Comment: Update the piece of code throwing this error

Comment: First of all, how are You executing this, in what environment, some sample code, is this concurent run, on remote machine... Please before expecting answer on general exception, provide as many as possible details.

Comment: It might be if You are running in concurrent run that You ran out of instances. Or instances are not closing properly.

Comment: @Kovacic While you edit a question/answer please don't `blockquote` the _code_ or _error stack trace_ else debugging the _code_ or _error stack trace_ becomes difficult.